# Sed + Regex which will match any line except those that start with a backtick

Tags: macos, sed, regex-negation, regexp-replace

I am trying to come up with a sed statement that will match a regex to include every line that does not start with a backtick `.

The goal is to prepend something on every line that does not start with a backtick.

The backtick can be at the start of the line or preceded by one or more blank space (or tab), any other line else I need to match, even the lines that have a backtick *not* at the beginning.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cat myfile.txt
`this line starts with backtick`

  `this one does too, but there are some spaces`

!some stuff on May 14 19:52:58 2020

more stuff *(&) 243123123123
  indented stuff
  indented stuff

string here that is nothing special
*here is an asterisk

  match `this line`
  1 number one
  2 number two

 `ignore this one`
```

And here is my sed expression (on Mac).

```
sed -e 's/^\([^[\s*`].*\)/--matched--\1/g' myfile.txt

`this line starts with backtick`

--matched--  `this one does too, but there are some spaces`

--matched--!some stuff on May 14 19:52:58 2020

--matched--more stuff *(&) 243123123123
--matched--  indented stuff
--matched--  indented stuff

string here that is nothing special
*here is an asterisk

--matched--  match `this line`
--matched--  1 number one
--matched--  2 number two

--matched-- `ignore this one`
```

Edit: clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to match the ones you want to ignore, then negate the match.   Here is a POSIX compliant way to do that:

```
sed --posix '/^[[:space:]]*`/!{/^$/!s/^/--matched---/}' ./myfile.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed --posix '/^[[:space:]]*`/!{/^$/!s/^/--matched---/}' ./myfile.txt
`this line starts with backtick`

  `this one does too, but there are some spaces`

--matched---!some stuff on May 14 19:52:58 2020

--matched---more stuff *(&) 243123123123
--matched---  indented stuff
--matched---  indented stuff

--matched---string here that is nothing special
--matched---*here is an asterisk

--matched---  match `this line`
--matched---  1 number one
--matched---  2 number two

  `ignore this one`
```

Comment: Thanks, what I really want to do is prepend every line (that does not start with a `) with something else. I can probably take this approach and do it in two steps, but I was hoping to do it all in one go.

Comment: @yeahb2018 updated my proof of concept to show how that would be done.

Comment: The "proof of concept" is for the correct solution, which is NOT the thing in your first line. The first line uses the `-n` flag and the `p` command - not what the (correct) solution in the Proof of Concept does.

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX this worked great in Linux, but it looks like my mac does not like it (BSD). I'll do some research, but at least on Linux (GNU) it works exactly as I need.

Comment: @yeahb2018 hmm, not sure why that's the case, the command i'm using is POSIX compliant.  You can check for yourself (on Linux) by adding the `--posix` option directly after the call to `sed`.  You should still get the same output.   What is BSD `sed` telling you?

Comment: @SiegeX, I found that I need to use `''` to make it run. However, it does not perform the prepending:

```
sed '' '/^[[:space:]]*`/!{/^$/!s/^/--matched---/}' ./file
sed: /^[[:space:]]*`/!{/^$/!s/^/--matched---/}: No such file or directory
`this line starts with backtick`

  `this one does too, but there are some spaces`

!some stuff on May 14 19:52:58 2020

more stuff *(&) 243123123123

```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  '/^\s*$\|^\s*`/!s/^/--matched--/' file
```

if the line is empty (may also contains only spaces) or the first non-space character is a tick, don't prepend `--matched--`.